# mvc 4 - web.config transforms is it possible to have 3 or more

Tags: web-config, transformation

I'm trying to work out whether it's possible to have more than 2 web.config transforms?

I quite often have situations where I'd like 3 as I often have to put test/demo versions of new releases up in a sandbox environment for clients to sign off on e.g.

web.debug.config
web.prerelease.config
web.release.config

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is and it's quite a nice and powerful feature. I'm using just [transformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326.aspx) for my release, but it is possible to use extra staging configuration. See [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs2010trainingcourse_webdevelopment_topic4.aspx).

Comment: This is a link-only answer.  Please provide additional information into the body of your answer.